# Entity Framework LINQ - How to perform an alphabetical string comparison e.g. Where Name > "Bob"

Tags: string, linq, entity-framework-4.1

In TSQL I can do this:

```
select * from Person where Name > 'Bob'
```

How do I do this with an entity framework LINQ query?

```
var results = db.People.Where(p => p.Name > "Bob"); // error
```

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/578231/issues-doing-a-string-comparison-in-linq][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/578231/issues-doing-a-string-comparison-in-linq

Comment: Ahh, thanks. I've voted to close my question as an exact duplicate of the one you referenced.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `.compareTo` to do a string comparison.