# How to compare a string column(as DateTime) in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a database with a ValidDate field - it's a string(we made a mistake, it should be a datetime, but we can't modify the database now.)

and now I want to compare this filed with a parameter(validDateStart) from the website:

```
priceList = priceList.Where(p => Convert.ToDateTime(p.ValidDate) >= Convert.ToDateTime(validDateStart));
var list = initPriceList.ToList();
```

But I get an error: The method ToDateTime is not implemented.

Can anybody give me some help? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not supported in Linq to Entities (nor Linq to SQL to my knowledge). Remember that your query is executed *on the database* - where there is simply no equivalent for `Convert.ToDateTime`.

Any string parsing in your query would really just be a workaround - as a real solution make those columns not strings but `datetime` in the database and you would not have this problem in the first place.

A hacky workaround would be materializing all rows (you can use `AsEnumerable()` for that), then doing the parsing - this will have bad performance though but might work good enough if there are few rows:

```
var startDate = DateTime.Parse(validDateStart);
var list = priceList.AsEnumerable()
                    .Where(p => DateTime.Parse(p.ValidDate) >= startDate);
                    .ToList();
```

**Edit:**

With your example update it looks like you can just do *string comparisons* to do what you wanted - granted it's still a hack but would perform much better than materializing all rows. This is possible because your date format puts the most significant numbers first, then the less significant parts - it's year, then month, then day (should this not be the case and the day comes before the month in your example this solution will not work).

Assuming your input string `validDateStart` is in the same format as well you can just do:

```
var list = priceList.Where(p => p.ValidDate.CompareTo(validDateStart) >=0);
                    .ToList();
```

string comparison with `String.CompareTo` seems to be support both in [Linq to Sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578231/issues-doing-a-string-comparison-in-linq) as well as [Linq to Entities](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/adodotnetentityframework/thread/98180ae0-4ccd-4ecd-89d5-576a04169219).

Comment: yes, you are right, It works well if I use AsEnumerable() for priceList. But as you said, I have so many records that I can't get all records in one request, the performance is too bad. Thanks!

Comment: what date format is your string column in? If it is ISO8601 you can get away with string comparisons - do you have an example?

Comment: with string comparions? I tried "priceList = priceList.Where(p => p.ValidDate.CompareTo(validDateStart) > 0);" , and still get the same error: The method CompareTo is not implemented:(

Comment: Can you give an example of what the date strings in the database look like?

Comment: The strings what do the strings in the database look like...e.g. "2012-05-12"

Comment: your idea is great, but I got a syntax error: Operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'

Comment: Are you sure it's not supported? Surely something like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466310 can be of assistance here.

Answer (score 0):

If all the records in your database always start with year, month and day (for example: the date format is yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss or yyyy/MM/dd or yyyyMMdd) no matter if it has separators or not. The thing is that the values should has a format where it starts with year, month and day.

You can do the following:

1: Convert your filter value (website) to the same format as you have in your database:

```
// DateTime format in database: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:ffffff
var from = filtro.CreationDateFrom?.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
var to = filtro.CreationDateTo?.AddDays(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

2: And write your query like this (using CompareTo method):

```
var query = (from x in ctx.TskTaskQueues
             where x.CreationDatetime.CompareTo(from) >= 0 
             && x.CreationDatetime.CompareTo(to) <= 0
             select x);
```

It worked for me!
I'm not using LinqToEntities but I'm using LinqConnect (for Oracle) that is similar to LinqEntities.

If you use a format like this dd-MM-yyyy, it probably will not work.