# casting a string to int insisde Linq lambda WHERE method

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I'm trying to select rows using a where clause on string columns and comparing to my variable zip which is int. Is this possible? I have tried int.Parse() inside the lambda but that doesn't work. Also it appears I cannot use the SQLFunctions calls since I am using .NET 3.5.

In the following PostcodeStart/PostcodeEnd are nvarchar, and zip is an int.

```
var re = postCodes.Where(
                x => x.PostcodeStart <= zip && x.PostcodeEnd >= zip);
```

Comment: Have you tried `(int) x.PostcodeStart`?

Comment: Yes, that won't allow me to compile. Cannot cast type of string to type of int...

Comment: What did not work with int.Parse exactly?

Comment: this is the error I get when trying to use int.Parse(): Method 'Int32 Parse(System.String)' has no supported translation to SQL.

Comment: How about `Convert.ToInt32(string_here)`?

Comment: Zip codes *aren't* numbers, and they are correctly stored in your database as strings, where (hopefully) they are validated before being stored. At any rate, if you hope to get an answer that does what you're trying to do, however misguided it may be, you need to include information about what LINQ provider you're using.

Comment: I think this answer here is what is needed.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/578231/issues-doing-a-string-comparison-in-linq

Answer (score -1):

Convert your int to a string before the Linq call:

```
string zipString = zip.ToString("00000");
var re = postCodes.Where(
                x => x.PostcodeStart.CompareTo(zipString) <= 0 
                  && x.PostcodeEnd.CompareTo(zipString) >= 0);
```

As a side note, an `int` is not a good type to hold a zip code.  Not only do you have to worry about leading zeros, but zip codes also have a four-digit extension (`"00000-0000"`).  Best to just leave them as strings.

Comment: Not to mention that at some point you're going to have to deal with other countries, and you'll have characters in the postal codes, too.

Comment: this does not work, you cannot use a greater than or less than operator when doing string comparison.

Comment: @WesleyLong "10222-SHOE" is the valid US zipcode of the Saks Fifth Avenue flagship in New York, thanks to a super great marketing ploy that the USPS somehow agreed to a decade ago. Yay corner cases!

Comment: @PrestonGuillot - I **DID NOT** know that!  I think I will win a few bar bets with that one.  Thanks!