# Documentdb linq query with string comparison

Tags: c#, linq, azure-cosmosdb

Though DocumentDb supports string range comparisons,

`client.CreateDocumentQuery<Family>(
    collectionLink,
    "SELECT * FROM Families f WHERE f.Address.State > 'NY'",
    new FeedOptions { EnableScanInQuery = true });`

You can also construct DocumentDB Linq queries like this.

`var zipLinqQuery =
    from z in db.ZIPMASTERs
    where z.CORP == listItem.CORP
    && z.ZIPBEG.CompareTo(listItem.ZIPCODE) <= 0
    && z.ZIPEND.CompareTo(listItem.ZIPCODE) >= 0
    select z;`

from [Issues Doing a String Comparison in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578231/issues-doing-a-string-comparison-in-linq)

I am unable to dynamically construct Linq string comparison queries using Linq Expressions:

`Expression<Func<string, string, bool>> stringCompare = (x, y) => x.CompareTo(y) > 0;
return Expression.Invoke(stringCompare, new[] { left, right });`

Produces the following output.

`(Invoke((x, y) => x.CompareTo(y), x.state, "NY") > 0)`

It seems, the DocumentDB API does not support Invoke and it does not support "Compare".  It supports "CompareTo" as described above but not when dynamically constructing a Linq Expression Tree.  Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way (where Item is the C# representation of your object):

```
Expression<Func<Item, bool>> filterDateExpression = d => d.DateUploadedUTC.CompareTo(fromS) >= 0 &&
                                                         d.DateUploadedUTC.CompareTo(toS) <= 0;
```

Hope this helps!